# It's difficult to learn ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Learning ember.js is a frustration for me:

**1. Lib script is hard to combination**:

I try to use :

- jquery 1.10.2
- handlebars 1.1.2
- ember 1.2.0
- ember-data 1.0.0 beta.1
- localstorage_adapter

but this combination would cause an error, it tell me: **The initializer 'dataAdapter' has already been registered**

But why? this script almost the latest!

I don't know what kind of combination could work, so I have to copy lib from other tutorial demo, finally this could work:

- jquery 1.9.1
- handlebars 1.0.0
- ember 1.0.0
- ember-data 1.0.0 beta.1
- localstorage_adapter

but most of them are old version!

**2. Ember.Object are most deprecated**

In the early tutorial:

- [Flame on! A beginner's guide to Ember.js](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/flame-on-a-beginners-guide-to-emberjs.html)
- [Want to Learn Ember.js? Start Here](http://elweb.co/want-to-learn-ember-js-start-here/)

they use the `Ember.Object` to build a model.

but in later tutorial:

- [An In-Depth Introduction To Ember.js](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/)
- [todomvc](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/emberjs/)

they use `DS.LSAdapter.extend` or `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;`, no `Ember.Object` at all.

And I can't find the `DS.LSAdapter` and `DS.FixtureAdapter` in [official api](http://emberjs.com/api/) or in the [official guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/)

Where does them come from?

So I feel learn `emberjs` is a frustrated tour for me?

Does anyone could give me some advise?

Comment: Hi, I feel your frustration, as it was with me. Prepare for a 4 to 6 week full time journey on Ember. Because that was my experience. And I am not at the top level now, as you can see from my questions on stackoverflow. At the end it is worth it, because it gives you back all that struggling time in smarter code. A good read is this: http://www.100percentjs.com/backbone-or-angular-or-ember-here-is-my-choice-and-why/?utm_source=Ember+Weekly&utm_campaign=02c7a3e720-Ember_Weekly_Issue_38&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_e96229d21d-02c7a3e720-100196777

Comment: "And I can't find the DS.LSAdapter and DS.FixtureAdapter in official api or in the official guide". FixtureAdapter: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-fixtures/. LSAdapter: "Our app looks to be working fine, so we are ready to switch to the real thing. We could enable the RESTAdapter, but then we would need a REST server on which we could perform GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests. Instead, let’s use LSAdapter, a third-party adapter that you can download on GitHub". If you're going to read a tutorial, READ it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll try to address your points in turn.

## 1. Dependency ordering

In [Ember.js' homepage](http://emberjs.com) there is a big button named `DOWNLOAD THE STARTER KIT` which gives you everything you need to bootstrap an Ember.js application. If you want something even more immediate, you can also use the [Ember.js JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/) to easily try the framework without even downloading anything.

On top of that there are [many](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember) [other](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit) ways to get started with developing Ember.js applications. There are even projects to make it easier to integrate with server-side frameworks, like [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails) and [Django](https://github.com/noirbizarre/django-ember), as well as adapters to a variety of datastores, like [django-tastypie](https://github.com/escalant3/ember-data-tastypie-adapter), [ActiveModelSerializer](https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/master/packages/activemodel-adapter), [Parse](https://github.com/clintjhill/ember-parse-adapter), etc, etc.

## 2. Ember.Object

`Ember.Object` is *not* deprecated. The difference between those tutorials is that the first ones are not using [Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data), while the latter do.
I'd advise for you to go through the [official Ember.js guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/) to get a great introduction to both the practicality of how to build an application, as well as the mindset behind the framework.

There are many other resources available at [EmberWatch](http://emberwatch.com/), which varying degrees of quality/up-to-date-ness.

Lastly, the best place to get help is the #ember.js channel on freenode (irc://irc.freenode.org/emberjs).

Hope this helps getting you started.

## P.S.

A hint that I usually give people that seems to be very helpful is to install [Ember Inspector](https://github.com/tildeio/ember-extension) and browse sites that use Ember.js to get a feel for how things work. Here's some of those sites: [Bustle](http://www.bustle.com), [Discourse](http://try.discourse.org/), [Vine](http://www.vine.co).

Answer (score 2):

Ember is so hard to learn, I've been really struggling with it for the last six weeks. As regards getting the libraries to work, I hope this doesn't sound obvious but I recommend you download the ember starter kit from http://emberjs.com/ and start working from within that instead. Ember-data is still in beta and can be problematic so watch out for that.

I started with the [An In-depth Introduction To Ember.js](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/#main_concepts) tutorial which you mentioned above and found that it goes through everything step by step, explaining all concepts very clearly for a CRUD app-

It uses the `FixtureAdapter` to build the model. More info on `FixtureAdapter` [here in the guides](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.FixtureAdapter.html#sts=DS.FixtureAdapter%20Class%20packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js:13)

Good luck..